# Protractor timeout after logging into site using onPrepare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, protractor

I have a test that should just check the title of the website after logging into the site. To perform the log in I use the onPrepare statement in my config file. 
When the site has been logged into the tests in my spec should run, but I keep getting

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.
```

If I add a beforeEach statement in my test spec, the test user is not logged in so I can't test all 'logged in' specific tests I need to run.

This is my config file:

```
'use strict';
var env = require('./enviroment');


exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,

    specs: [
        'photostream/*.spec.js'
    ],

    capabilities: {
        name: 'Chrome',
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    baseUrl: env.baseUrl,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    },
    onPrepare: function(){

        browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl);


        // find the sign in button
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('homepage_sign_in_btn')).click();
        browser.sleep(1000);

        // fire click event of the sign in button
        // check that the Sign In to Lifecake panel is opened
        // enter a email address
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('sign-in-menu-email')).sendKeys(env.testUserAcc.email);

        // enter the password
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('sign-in-menu-password')).sendKeys(env.testUserAcc.password);
        browser.sleep(5000);

        // click the sign in button
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('home_menu_sign_in_btn')).click();


        return browser.driver.wait(function(){
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){

                return url + '/index.html#/photos';
            })
        }, 5000)

    }
}
```

And this is my test spec file:

```
'use strict';
var PhotostreamHelper = require('./photostream.page.js');

describe('Tests for the Photostream - ',function(){
    it('The title of the site should be Lifecake', function () {

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Lifecake');
        browser.sleep(2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix that issue?